# Contact Form opening PHP file instead of showing Popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I have a contact form on my website that with the current code sends an email to the sender and the receiver, and all works fine. However, once completing the form, the page opens email.php instead of showing a popup that I hoped it would. I have no idea how to fix as I'm not used to writing for php and JS. Below is my code.

```
<form method="post" action="email.php" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_self" novalidate>
<input type="text" value="" name="full_name" class="fullname" id="mce-name" placeholder="full name" required>
<input type="text" value="" name="phone_num" class="phonenum" id="mce-phone" placeholder="phone number" required>
<br>
<input type="email" value="" name="email" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_cdb7b577e41181934ed6a6a44_e65110b38d" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
```

---

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@help.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $phone_num = $_POST['phone_num'];
    $subject = "Title";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = "Message";
    $message2 = "Message2";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $subject != '' && $message != '') {

            }
        } else {
            echo '<script>function displayPopup()
{
 alert("Form submitted!");
}<script>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why are you defining a function `displayPopup()` if you just want to show an alert?

Comment: I don't know PHP, JS. I've been using other people answers that I've found to try and solve the problem I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you only declare the popup function, you did not run `displayPopup()`

try to change to

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $subject != '' && $message != '') {

    } else {
        echo '<script>function displayPopup(){alert("Form submitted!");}';
        echo 'displayPopup();</script>
        ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it shows a popup, but still also redirects the page to email.php?

Comment: u put form action to email.php, that is why you post, it will land at email.php. if you do not want the user to land at email.php, what you could do is to use jquery show the pop up box when user submit, and then ajax post the email form to email.php

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure someone else knows how to do this, but I do not. I'll have to have a search around.

Comment: cool, just a hint, `$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").on("submit", function(e)
{ e.preventDefault();
    alert("Testmessage");

    // do ajax post now

});` put this on the same page as the email form, you can do some research on ajax form submission, there are a lot tutorials

Comment: Thank you though, even just looking at it, I have no idea where it goes. As a designer and not a developer, being assigned to this is just confusing.